# What does "claim knowledge" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Employees who will handle an edged object and **claim prior knowledge**,
>   will be required to demonstrate their experience in the safe handling
>   of the object.

I looked up a dictionary, and it seems "claim" here means obtain, but I am not sure. Does the bold part mean "obtain prior knowledge"?

Comment: You're using the wrong definition of claim. Here, it means to assert something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Employees who will handle an edged object and claim prior knowledge,

It means some of the Employees who will be handling edged object or who has been requested to do so, has said that they have experience, knowledge from past to do the task. simply it means they know what they are doing and doesn't need any training.

> will be required to demonstrate their experience in the safe handling
>   of the object.

That means if certain employee has noted in their request, that they have previous knowledge, will have to demonstrate it. to verify that what they said was the truth

Comment: Then does "claim prior knowledge" mean that they are already educated with the knowledge?

Comment: claim prior knowledge means they say they have knowledge about the task by previous experience. could be truth or a lie. Claim means they imply that they have the knowledge. to verify that being true or a lie, that's what employers require demonstration